# What is the gesture of hiding your mouth called?

Tags: word-request

What is called the action of hiding your mouth with your hand? I find it to be a very peculiar behavior, but I am thinking this was something that was done by aristocrats in the real word, so certainly there must be a word. Is there a word associated with such gesture?

[image]

Comment: Simply "covering your mouth"?

Comment: Why on earth would you specifically single out ***aristocrats*** as people who do this? Peasants do it too! Note that in some contexts, ***muffle*** (as verb or noun) may be relevant, but generally speaking English doesn't have a standard single-word term for hiding one's mouth (behind a hand, a fan, or a mask, for example).

Comment: @Mast That seems to be the right phrase. There's a book chapter on body language that calls it that repeatedly:  https://tinyurl.com/y538vgy8

Comment: @Jack I principally don't follow URL-shorteners, so I don't know what book you're talking about.

Comment: @Mast Suit yourself. BTW, by the word "principally", do you mean "as a matter of principle"? That's an unusual usage.

Comment: _You_ may find it peculiar, but it's an instinctive part of body language for many people when they feel insecure or have to deceive someone